# Deforming a mesh in BGE runtime

Tags: game-engine, physics, rigid-body-simulation

I have two objects in my scene. One of them is a rigid body and it has to collide with the another one (soft body). I need to do the rigid body deforms the softbody in runtime and the deformation has to be plastic. I tried setting the object as Soft body in Game Render and setting Plastic = 100, but I think these parameters don't affect in the game engine. What could I do? I think changing the position of each vertex of the softbody when the rigid body touch it could be computationally expensive.

Answer (score 1):

The Blender Game Engine and the Blender's simulation system use two different pysics solvers. To see the game physics settings you have to set the Blender engine to 'Blender Game':
[image]
But the softbody settings of the game engine do not offer any settings for plastic deformation:
[image]

So why is there a difference? 
The solver used in the animation system is more powerfull and accurate, but as you may have noticed it is much too slow for a game.
The solver in the Game Engine on the other hand uses a very fast position-based softbody simulation called Shape Matching (see [the paper](http://www.beosil.com/download/MeshlessDeformations_SIG05.pdf) for more information). While the paper also describes the implementation of plastic deformations, this is either not implemented or not activated in Blender.

Comment: The paper will probably not help you with Blender, I just added it for completeness. If you are interested in the topic though, have a look. The concepts in the paper are not that hard to understand if you have basic knowledge in linear algebra. And don't let the formulas scare you off ;)